# I have multiple should cases for elastic search yet only first one works

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have shared the script giving error. It only matches the first should case and not the rest

```
 BoolQueryBuilder boolqueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
 boolqueryBuilder
            .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("dishName", (userSearchCriteriaContainer.getSearchString() == null ? "" : userSearchCriteriaContainer.getSearchString())))
            .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("cuisineTypes", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getCuisineTypes())) )
            .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("mealType", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getDishList())) )
            .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("preparationTime", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getPreparationTime())) );

 SearchRequest searchRequest = config.client().prepareSearch("dishes").setQuery(boolqueryBuilder).setExplain(true).setFrom(0).setSize(100).request();

 org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = config.restClient().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This query will return document if any of the should clause matches it. Can you add sample document , except ed and actual result for them

Comment: Can you share the response (document) which you get after executing the above query?

Answer (score 0):

When there is no ‘must’, ‘should’ must match a  condition.

You can add it to the back (.minimumShouldMatch(2))

At least two conditions.

```
boolqueryBuilder
        .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhrasePrefixQuery("dishName", (userSearchCriteriaContainer.getSearchString() == null ? "" : userSearchCriteriaContainer.getSearchString())))
        .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("cuisineTypes", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getCuisineTypes())) )
        .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("mealType", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getDishList())) )
        .should(QueryBuilders.termQuery("preparationTime", String.valueOf(userSearchCriteriaContainer.getPreparationTime())) )
        .minimumShouldMatch(2);
```